# Erro ao ler um arquivo: Error in scan line 6 did not have 63 elements

Tags: r

Sou iniciante no `R` e não consigo ler o arquivo com o qual estou trabalhando.

```
tab1<-read.table("savedrecs.txt", header=T, sep="\t") 
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
line 6 did not have 63 elements
```

Comment: Este é o StackOverflow em português. As perguntas devem ser feitas neste idioma.

Answer (score 2):

Sem ter acesso ao arquivo `savedrecs.txt`, fica impossível dar uma resposta definitiva para esta questão. Só é possível especular. Ao que tudo indica, o problema está no argumento `sep="\t"`. Esta opção indica ao `R` que as colunas do teu arquivo estão separadas por marcas de tabulação.

Abra o seu arquivo no Bloco de Notas (ou algum programa similar) para descobrir como as colunas estão separadas. O mais provável é que estejam separadas por espaços. Se for assim, utilize o comando

```
tab1<-read.table("savedrecs.txt", header=T, sep=" ")
```

para ler os dados. Se as colunas estiverem separadas por vírgula ou ponto e vírgula, utilize

```
tab1<-read.table("savedrecs.txt", header=T, sep=",")
tab1<-read.table("savedrecs.txt", header=T, sep=";")
```

respectivamente.

É muito pouco provável que algum outro separador de colunas esteja sendo utilizado. Se mesmo assim não for possível a leitura dos dados, tente abrir o arquivo no Excel, salve uma nova versão dele como `.csv` e leia esta nova versão utilizando `sep=","`.

Answer (score 2):

Com as limitações que temos para responder apontadas pelo [@Marcus Nunes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/49033/marcus-nunes), eu te aconselho usar a função `fread()` do pacote `data.table`. A grande vantagem neste caso é que você não precisa informar o delimitador ou se há cabeçalho (header), pois a função detecta eles automaticamente.

```
install.package('data.table')
library(data.table)
tab1 <- fread("savedrecs.txt")
```

Além disso `fread()` é rápida demais!